# Is there any better play than the 3-move mate?

Tags: checkmate, history

I know how to cause a checkmate in three moves. Are there any better ones? I've been told that  there is a two move one but, I have never found someone who can do it. Is it just a legend that has happened once or twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a two-move mate: the [*Fool's Mate*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fool's_mate). However, it requires White to be, as the name implies, extremely foolish!

```
[FEN ""]
1.g4 e5 2.f3 Qh4#
```

As you can see, this mate relies on White advancing pawns without any regard for his King's safety. There's no way to *force* a two move checkmate (if there were, Chess would be an awfully boring game!).

As to whether it's ever occurred in real (master) play, I can't find any record of it, though the Wikipedia article mentions Teed vs. Delmar, 1896, where a very similar mate is delivered a few moves later.

Comment: I remember teaching someone to play and the first game we played was exactly this series of four moves.  It was surreal.

Comment: In her final round Gibralter Masters game, Hou Yifan attempted something like this as white, however black did not play 1. e5. Read about that infamous game/story for instance here: https://chessbase.in/news/gibhou/

Answer (score 1):

You can NOT cause a mate in 3 or 2 or any low number.

If the other player is truly stupid or messing with you then it might be possible to mate in 2 for black but white to do it would take 2½